# Ruby how to get file from public dir?

Tags: ruby

```
def get_xml
    path = "ddd-66252.pdf" // in public

    way = File.basename(path)
    diff = File.read(path)
    render :xml => diff
end
```

How i can get file from path and need to look like file

Comment: The method is named `get_xml` but should return a PDF file? The use of the `render` lets me wonder if you use Ruby on Rails or another web framework?

Comment: @spickermann i will do it with pdf-parser after catch file. proccess is pdf to xml convert but it is not my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Ruby on Rails because you mention a `public` folder and have a `render` method in your code. In Ruby on Rails you can use [`send_file`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#sending-files) in your controller like this to send files to the browser:

```
def send_pdf
  send_file(
    Rails.root.join('public', 'ddd-66252.pdf'),
    filename: 'ddd-66252.pdf',
    type: 'application/pdf'
  )
end
```